# How to represent part of BPMN workflow that is automated by system?

Tags: workflow, modeling, bpmn

I am documenting a user workflow where part of the flow is automated by a system (e.g. if the order quantity is less than 10 then approve the order immediately rather than sending it to a staff for review).

I have swim lanes that goes from people to people but not sure where I can fit this system task/decision path.  What's the best practice?  Possibly a dumb idea but I'm inclined to create a new swim lane and call it the "system".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System tasks (service tasks in BPMN) are usually done on behalf of an actor, so in my opinion it is useful to position them in the lane for that actor.

Usually such design also help to keep the diagram easy to read by limiting the number of transition between "users" lanes and "system" lane.

Comment: In an example I recently worked on, this ended up being counter-intuitive. I had a website pool with 1 lane in which the website visitor was going through an order and payment process. I needed a way to model activities done by the website, like sending messages to 3rd parties and logging information for commissions. The "on behalf of" actor would have been the website owner, but this made no sense visually. In the end I simply added a "system" lane.

Answer (score 3):

The approach of detaching system task into separate lane is quite possible as BPMN 2.0 specification *does not* explicitly specify meaning of lanes and says something like that:

> Lanes are used to organize and categorize Activities within a Pool.
>   The meaning of the Lanes is up to the modeler. BPMN does not specify
>   the usage of Lanes. Lanes are often used for such things as internal
>   roles (e.g., Manager, Associate), systems (e.g., an enterprise
>   application), an internal department (e.g., shipping, finance), etc.

So you are completely free to fill them with everything you want. 
However, your case is quite evident and doesn't require such separation at all. According to your description we have typical conditional activity which can be expressed via Service task or Sub-process. These are 2 different approaches and they hold different semantics.

- According to BPMN specification **Service Task** *is a task that uses some sort of service, which could be a Web service or an automated application.* I.e it is usually used when modeller don't want to decompose some process and is intended to *outsource* it to some external tool or agent.
- Another cup of tea is **Sub-process**, which is typically used when you
  want *to wrap some complex piece of workflow for reuse* or if that
  piece of workflow *can be decomposed into sub-elements*.

In your use case sub-process is a thing of choice. It is highly adjustable, transparent and maintainable. For example, inside sub-process you can use Business Rules Engine for your condition parameter (Order Quantity) and flexibly adjust its value on-the-fly.
In greater detail you can learn the difference of these approcahes from [this blog](http://blog.goodelearning.com/bpmn/common-bpmn-modeling-mistakes-activities/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique of expressing system tasks/decisions via dedicated participant/lane. Then all system tasks are collocated on a system lane.